# Python Random Generator

Tags: python, random, generator

Basically i need some quick help. I'm making a program where I am using two random generators to generate numbers.

1. First generator, between 2-14 each number representing a card. Numbers 11, 12 13, and 14 represent Jack, Queen, King & Ace respectively.
2. Second random generator generating numbers 15-18 to represent the type of card for example 15, 16, 17, 18 would represent Hearts, Spades, Diamonds & Clubs respectively.

What the outcome of the generators should come to is the first generator generated a number 8 and the second generator generated the number 17. I then want it to translate this to read: "8 of Diamonds".

Here is my code so far:

```
import random

Player1 = input("Enter Name Of Player1")
Card = random.randint(2, 14)
Suit = random.randint(15,18)
if Card == 11:
    print("Jack")
elif Card == 12:
    print("Queen")
elif Card == 13:
    print("King")
elif Card == 14:
    print("Ace")
else:
    print(Card)
```

Comment: Why 15-18 for suits? Why not just 0-3 so you can look them up in a list?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, using [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) and [string formats](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#format):

```
import random

suits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
numbers = [
    '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',
    'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']

print('{number} of {suit}'.format(
    number=random.choice(numbers),
    suit=random.choice(suits)))

>> Ace of Hearts
```

You could use some `range` function to generate the numbers, but in this particular case, you can probably get away with hardcoding it. Note that strings are probably the better option as well because you're mixing that with `'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', and 'Ace'`.

Comment: NumPy is a pretty heavyweight dependency, and it's not needed for this: the std. lib. `random` module has a `choice` function.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
import random

Player1 = raw_input("Enter Name Of Player1")
suits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
numbers = {2:'2', 3:'3', 4:'4', 5:'5', 6:'6', 7:'7', 8:'8', 9:'9', 10:'10', 11:'Jack', 12:'Queen', 13:'King', 14:'Ace'}
Card = random.randint(2, 14)
Suit = random.randint(0, 3)
print '{0} of {1}'.format(numbers[Card], suits[Suit])
```